# Composer fails when installing a dependency of a dependency, but not when the dependency is installed directly

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, package, project-management

I have a main composer.json that has the following among others

```
"type": "project",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../packages/example/example/",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "example/example": "@dev"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

And I also have a composer for my `example/example` package that contains:

```
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "baum/baum": "1.1.*",
    "roave/security-advisories": "@dev"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

When I run either `composer install` or `composer update` in my main project (first composer), the package `baum/baum` gets installed, but `roave/security-advisories` does not even though my minimum-stability is set to `dev`.

Is there a way to force the inclusion of `@dev` dependencies of dependencies in the main project?

Comment: I have the same problem (with the same package), and I suspect the only way this is possible is to require the `"roave/security-advisories": "@dev"` package in your main `composer.json`. Therefore I also think this should not be included in a library.